# Python: read through multiple but not all csv files in my folder

Tags: python, csv

I want to read some csv files from my folder and concatenate them to a big pandas dataframe. All of my csv files end with a number, and I only want to read files whose number end with (6~10, 16~20, 26~30.) My goal is to read the files iteratively. Attached is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd

data_one = pd.read_csv('Datafile-6.csv', header=None)
for i in range(7,11):
    data99 = pd.read_csv('Datafile-'+i+'*.csv', header=None) #this line needs work
    data_one = pd.concat([data_one, data99.iloc[:,1]],axis=1,ignore_index=True)

data_two = pd.read_csv('Datafile-16.csv', header=None)
for j in range(17,21):
    #Repeat similar process
```

What should I do about 'data99' such that 'data_one' contains columns from 'Datafile-6' through 'Datafile-10'?

The first five rows of data_one should look like this, after getting data from Datafiles 6-10.

```
      0         1         2         3         4         5
0 -40.0  0.179836  0.179630  0.179397  0.179192  0.179031
1 -39.0  0.183696  0.183441  0.183204  0.182977  0.182795
2 -38.0  0.186720  0.186446  0.186191  0.185949  0.185762
3 -37.0  0.189490  0.189207  0.188935  0.188686  0.188475
4 -36.0  0.192154  0.191851  0.191569  0.191301  0.191086
```

Column 0 is included in all of the data files, so I'm only concatenating column 1 of all of the subsequent data files.

Comment: I have added the first five rows in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `glob` module:

```
import glob, os
import pandas as pd

path =r'C:\YourFolder' #path to folder with .csv files
all = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
d_frame = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
for file_ in all:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=None, header=0)
    if df['YourColumns'].tail(1).isin([6,7,8,9,10,16,17,18,19,20,26,27,28,29,30]) == True: #You can modify list with conditions you need
        list_.append(df)
d_frame = pd.concat(list_)
```

Comment: What I hope for in your if statement is to look the file name that ends with 6,7,8,9 etc. I think your if-statement looks for the last entry of a particular column in all of my files?